# Throws NPE for imservice.username in android

Tags: android

Hi in the below code NPE 
`String result1 = imService.DispalyGroupDetails(imService.getUsername());`in this line showing error. I want the username.I am accessing the username by using imservice calss.These same username I am accessing in another places it's working fine But In the below code only giving problem.

Can any one help me

**FriendList **

```
    public class FriendList extends ListActivity 
    {
        private static final int ADD_NEW_FRIEND_ID = Menu.FIRST;
        private static final int CREATE_GROUP_ID = Menu.FIRST+1;
        private static final int EXIT_APP_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
        private IAppManager imService = null;
        private FriendListAdapter friendAdapter;

        public String ownusername = new String();

        private class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
        {       
            class ViewHolder {
                TextView text,text1;

                ImageView icon;
            }
            private LayoutInflater mInflater;
            private Bitmap mOnlineIcon;
            private Bitmap mOfflineIcon;        

            private FriendInfo[] friends = null;


            public FriendListAdapter(Context context) {
                super();            

                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                mOnlineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.greenstar);
                mOfflineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.redstar);

            }

            public void setFriendList(FriendInfo[] friends)
            {
                this.friends = friends;
                }


            public int getCount() {     

                return friends.length;
            }


            public FriendInfo getItem(int position) {           

                return friends[position];
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {

                return 0;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewHolder holder;


                if (convertView == null) 
                {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_list_screen, null);


                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.text1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

                    holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);                                       

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }   
                else {

                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }


                holder.text.setText(friends[position].userName);
                //holder.text1.steText(groupname);
                holder.icon.setImageBitmap(friends[position].status == STATUS.ONLINE ? mOnlineIcon : mOfflineIcon);

                return convertView;
            }

        }
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.list_screen);



          try {
            String result1 = imService.DispalyGroupDetails(imService.getUsername());
            System.out.println(result1);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          friendAdapter = new FriendListAdapter(this);

    }
```

**GroupList **

```
public class GroupList extends ListActivity 
{

    boolean[] checkBoxState;
    boolean isChecked;
    String check;
    ListView users;
    int position;
    private IAppManager imService = null;
    ArrayList<FriendInfo> result = new ArrayList<FriendInfo>();
    private FriendListAdapter friendAdapter;

    public String ownusername = new String();

    private class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {   
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView text;
            ImageView icon;
            CheckBox check1;



        }

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Bitmap mOnlineIcon;
        private Bitmap mOfflineIcon;        

        private FriendInfo[] friend = null;





        public FriendListAdapter(Context context) {
            super();            

            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            mOnlineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.greenstar);
            mOfflineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.redstar);

        }

        public void setFriendList(FriendInfo[] friends)
        {
            this.friend = friends;

        }


        public int getCount() {     

            return friend.length;
        }


        public FriendInfo getItem(int position) {           

            return friend[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return 0;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;


            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grouplist, null);


                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                holder.check1 = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            }           

            else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            }


            holder.text.setText(friend[position].userName);
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(friend[position].status == STATUS.ONLINE ? mOnlineIcon : mOfflineIcon);

            final ArrayList<String> checkedFriends = new ArrayList<String>();
            checkBoxState = new boolean[friend.length];
            holder.check1.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
            holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    checkBoxState[position]=isChecked;

                    if(isChecked){

                       check=friend[position].userName;

                    } 

                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.group_list_screen);

        Button create=(Button)findViewById(R.id.create);


        friendAdapter = new FriendListAdapter(this); 


        friendAdapter.getCheckedItems();
        create.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "unchecked" })
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String groupname = getIntent().getStringExtra("nick");

                            try {



                                String result1 = imService.CreateGroup(groupname,imService.getUsername(),friendAdapter.getCheckedItems());
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }



                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group Created Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });    

    }
```

Comment: Strange you know `NPE` in which line but not able to find why? where you are initializing `imService` ?

Comment: private IAppManager imService = null;

Comment: try to initializing it by calling constructor of `IAppManager` class like `imService=new IAppManager()`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Second class it working fine without intialization

Answer (score 0):

You defined imService as null:

```
private IAppManager imService = null;
```

And you never initialized it and then you are trying to call

```
String result1 = imService.DispalyGroupDetails(imService.getUsername());
```

And hence nullpointer exception. You may want to initialize imService.

Comment: Hi In the GroupList class working imService.getUsername() without intialize the imService